# Long foreach on PHP 504 error

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, foreach

I am developing software documentation control vehicles.

I need to generate a report of all companies that use the software and determine their vehicles to todods which have permits to drive or not.

For a vehicle has permissions, more than 10 documents are controlled, with expiration dates, paper stocks, etc.

The report should be similar to this:

Company 1:
-Vehicle 1
-Vehicle 2
-Vehicle 3
-....

firm 2
-Vehicle 232
-Vehicle 456
-....

I do a foreach per vehicle, and a foreach per document.

For the type of controls to do, it is impossible to do everything in a single query MySQL.

My problem is that it takes so long that the nginx always throws me "504 Gateway Time-out".

I wonder if there is some technique to run the server-side script as if it were in the background, and when finished save the file to the server and notify the user via an e-mail.

I'm having this problem in several other projects, where CRONS run that update data. And if the volume of data is very large, always scritp stops before finishing.
The server is nginx / 1.4.6 (Ubuntu). I do not want to increase the max_execution_time.

Comment: You could set `fastcgi_read_timeout` for the specific file higher (as long as you need + a bit reserve) in the nginx vhost config.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring user abort might help you - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

However, I would either revise the process to eliminate `foreach` loops, or just split the process into smaller chunks and set up a cron job to do one chunk at a time.